# Cornerstone image viewer Resize canvas size onclick button

Tags: javascript, jquery

Am using Cornerstone Image viewer.
I want to split the screen into 3 columns.
Initially left and right side div should hide and middle div should full window size display.
when i click show left div screen has to reduce and fit into 2 div's.
When i click show right div hide left and show with right and middle div's.

```
function resizeStudyViewer() {
    var studyRow = $(studyViewer).find('.studyContainer')[0];
    var height = $(studyRow).height();
    var width = $(studyRow).width();
    $(seriesList).height("100%");
    $(parentDiv).width(width - $(studyViewer).find('.thumbnailSelector:eq(0)').width());
    $(parentDiv).css({ height: '100%' });                            
    $(imageViewerElement).css({ height: $(parentDiv).height() - $(parentDiv).find('.text-center1:eq(0)').height() });

    $(imageViewerElement).css({ height: '100%'});

    imageViewer.forEachElement(function (el, vp) {
        cornerstone.resize(el, true);
        if ($(el).data('waiting')) {
            var ol = vp.find('.overlay-text');
            if (ol.length < 1) {
                ol = $('<div class="overlay overlay-text">Please drag a stack onto here to view images.</div>').appendTo(vp);
            }
            var ow = vp.width() / 2, oh = vp.height() / 2;
            ol.css({ top: oh, left: ow - (ol.width() / 2) });
        }
    });
}
// Call resize viewer on window resize
$(window).resize(function () {
    resizeStudyViewer();
});
```

Comment: Can you provide an illustration?

Comment: u can refer ohif image viewer (http://34.224.187.57:3000/studylist) In this link second screen splitting and resizing canvas size

Comment: It won't open. Can you add the image to your question?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VK7dmBPMJZWfsE3QCjBW_h-prb6j-XZn/view?usp=sharing